# I installed wine in order to use silverlight. uninstalling wine and silverlight 5.1

Tags: wine, moonlight

I installed wine in order  to use silverlight. Now Software center doesn't  run because I get a small message from some program installing silverlight 5.1. How can I unistall this and revert back to the situation before I did this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wine Uninstaller. Run, in a terminal:

`wine uninstaller`

Find your program and delete it. Remember that you can always kill Wine and its processes with the command `wineserver -k` instead of deleting them.